# Mock/stub data with Jest with models that have autoIncrement.MongooseAutoIncrementId.plugin business. Cannot read property 'Mongoose....' of undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mongoose-schema, mongoose-auto-increment

Hello I am trying to write some unit test and while I import some needed interface to implement the unit testing I keep run into this error " Cannot read property 'MongoseAutoIncrementId' of undefined".
There is a model that its schema used the plugin

```
Schema.plugin(autoIncrement.MongooseAutoIncrementID.plugin, { modelName: "ModelName", field: "UID" });
```

I don't really need this model to implement the unit test, the model was from a package that was imported to my project so I cannot remove the auto increment business out either or change anything inside the model.

My question is how should I mock the data and model to be able to import, declare service or consumer object without getting the error?

Thank you